# Remove unwanted attributes of Product

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

i create Item Type Books with following attribute title,author,publishingAttribute,isAvailable
all are String except isAvailable this is boolean there is no extend the any class but when i run select from HAC it show extra attribute i want to remove this attribute i can how i can delete it.

This is my item type

```
 [<itemtype generate="false" code="Books" autocreate="true">
            <deployment table="Books" typecode="20000" />
                <attributes>
                    <attribute qualifier="title" type="java.lang.String">
                        <description>Book Title</description>
                        <modifiers initial="true"/>
                        <persistence type="property"/>
                    </attribute>

                    <attribute qualifier="author" type="java.lang.String">
                        <description>>Book Author Name</description>
                   <persistence type="property"/>
                    </attribute>

                    <attribute qualifier="publishingAttribute" type="java.lang.String">
                    <description>>Book Author Attribute</description>
                        <persistence type="property"/>
                    </attribute>


                <attribute qualifier="isAvailable" type="java.lang.Boolean">
                <description>Available or not </description>
                        <persistence type="property"/>enter image description here
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
            </itemtype>][1]
```

Comment: why is that extra attribute visible in hmc ? Is it possible that it was needed in the past, but somewhere along the line it was deleted ? You need to understand this first in order to not delete relevant data

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following `itemtype` definitions available in `core-items.xml`:

```
<itemtype code="Item"
          extends=""
          jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item"
          deployment="de.hybris.platform.persistence.Item"
          autocreate="true"
          generate="false"
          abstract="true">
    <attributes>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="creationtime" type="java.util.Date">
            <persistence type="cmp" qualifier="creationTimestampInternal"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="true" optional="true" initial="true"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="modifiedtime" type="java.util.Date">
            <persistence type="cmp" qualifier="modifiedTimestampInternal"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="itemtype" type="ComposedType">
            <persistence type="cmp" qualifier="typePkString"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="owner" type="Item">
            <persistence type="cmp" qualifier="ownerPkString"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="true" optional="true" private="false" initial="true"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="pk" type="de.hybris.platform.core.PK">
            <persistence type="cmp" qualifier="pkString"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="true" optional="false"/>
        </attribute>
         <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="sealed" type="boolean">
            <persistence type="property" qualifier="sealed"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>

<itemtype code="ExtensibleItem"
          extends="Item"
          jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.ExtensibleItem"
          deployment="de.hybris.platform.persistence.ExtensibleItem"
          autocreate="true"
          generate="false" abstract="true">
</itemtype>

<itemtype code="LocalizableItem"
          extends="ExtensibleItem"
          jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.c2l.LocalizableItem"
          deployment="de.hybris.platform.persistence.c2l.LocalizableItem"
          autocreate="true"
          generate="false" abstract="true">
</itemtype>

<itemtype code="GenericItem"
          extends="LocalizableItem"
          jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.GenericItem"
          deployment="de.hybris.platform.persistence.GenericItem"
          autocreate="true"
          generate="false">
</itemtype
```

As you can see, `GenericItem` extends `LocalizableItem`, `LocalizableItem` extends `ExtensibleItem`, and `ExtensibleItem` extends `Item` i.e. `GenericItem ▸ LocalizableItem ▸ ExtensibleItem ▸ Item`. It means that `GenericItem` inherits 6 attributes, `creationtime,  modifiedtime, itemtype, owner, pk, and sealed` from `Item`.

When you create an `itemtype` without extending another `itemtype`, it extends `GenericItem` by default and therefore you will see all these 6 inherited attributes (`creationtime,  modifiedtime, itemtype, owner, pk, and sealed`) in that `itemtype`.

For example, the following Flexible Search query will return these 6 inherited attributes (`creationtime,  modifiedtime, itemtype, owner, pk, and sealed`) along with the attributes you have declared in your `itemtype` definition:

```
SELECT * FROM {Books}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for that  i have one more question can i change development table after creating once ? i yes how i can change 
Thank in advance

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument mismatch trying to set value 'ArticleApprovalStatus.check(check(8796093087835))' for attribute de.hybris.platform.jalo.GenericItem.approvalStatus (got de.hybris.platform.jalo.enumeration.EnumerationValue, expected de.hybris.platform.jalo.product.Product). 

This is real error how i can solve ?

Comment: What is ItemModel then? Does by default itemtype doesn't extend ItemModel? @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: @HimanshuJain - I missed your comment somehow. While looking for something else, I just came across this page. `ItemModel`  is generated by Hybris. If you configure an `itemtype` in an `items.xml`, Hybris generates many java files e.g. for an `itemtype code="MyType"`, files like `MyTypeModel.java`, `GeneratedMyType.java`, `MyType.java` etc. will be generated by Hybris when you build the system.